# What purpose does experience serve after reaching summoner level 30?

Tags: league-of-legends

After a player reaches level 30, does experience earned do anything for the player?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You no longer gain experience after level 30, as there is nowhere further to progress to.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_%28summoner%29

You do, however continue gaining Influence Points; spendable on runes, rune pages, and champions; so there remain incentives for continued play. (In addition to fun, of course.)

Comment: who cares about the fun though, I am here for those little shiny runes who I relentlessly collect day and night